# Does Private Internet Access VPN Block Tethering Detection

Tags: iphone, tethering

If I use the Private Internet Access VPN software while tethered to my iphone can T-Mobile still detect that I am tethering?

So, then since im requesting data from the vpn and since that data is encrypted can they tell that im tethered, or does it look like regular mobile data?

Answer (score 0):

The phone will know that it is connected to something and sending data to it. So yes.